# How to generate random numbers between given range?VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers

I'm trying to create `computer guess game` in which i think number between `1-100` and computer generate random number between `1-100` and user give response that generated number is too low or too high or correct guess.E.G computer generate number `23` if i give input `L` then next time it will generate number between 1 t0 23.If next time if it display 10 then i press `H` then it will generate numbers between 10 and 23 hope you understand what i am trying to do.And same for `H`.
Thanks
Here is my code i try

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare Variables
    Dim strGuess As Char
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim low As Integer
    Dim high As Integer
   Line1:
    MessageBox.Show("You pick a number between 0 and 100 and i will try to guess.Respond")
    answer = random.Next(1, 100)
    strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & answer, "Number Guessing Game")

    ' lstGuesses.Items.Add(strGuess)'
    low = answer
  Line2:
    If (CChar(strGuess) = CChar("L")) Then

        low = random.Next(1, low)
        strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & low, "Number Guessing Game")

    End If

    GoTo Line2

    high = answer
  Line7:
    If (CChar(strGuess) = CChar("H")) Then

        high = random.Next(high, 100)
        strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & high, "Number Guessing Game ")

    End If
    GoTo Line7
 End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know about VB but want to ask that, is there any loop at this code? I mean once you hit to H button, how algorythm comes back to Line2 again to check if you hit to L button?

Comment: Thanks for response.I use `random` function if i press `H` then it will generate random number between previous number and 100 and if i press `L` then it will generate number between 1 and previous number .I use if statements for check `L` and `H`

Comment: Another question about algorythm. Lets say computer choose 15 but i want 30. 15<30 and low=answer that means 15 now so when i hit to L button,  It will generate another number between 1 and low, that means 1 and 15 and this number will be even lesser. Should'nt it rise the number if its lower? but if you mean already "It's lower" with pressing to Low, its ok.

Comment: I think number between `1-100` and computer guess my number and i give response to computer that generated number is too low,too high or right in the form of `L` ,`H` and `R` .Example: if choose number just keep in my mind 40 and computer display `is it 20` then i put in input box `L` mean too low then computer will generate next numbers greater then `20` next time if computer display 45 then i put `H` mean too high then computer generate number blow 45 ,Hope you understand

Comment: e.g if i think 50 number in my mind .Computer generate any number between 1 and 100.If computer display is it 60 then i give response input box `L` then computer generate blow 60 random numbers.Next if it display 40 then i press `H` then i will generate numbers between 40-60

Comment: Your first example 9 min ago, You choosed 40, computer choosed 20 and you gave L input. Second example, You choosed 50, computer choosed 60 and you again gave L input. There is a problem about that, they are different situations but i think you want to do second one, code is more suitable for that.  Hope someone helps. Good coding.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy please check this one [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/c4520011bc.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code,

```
Public Class Form1
Dim strGuess As Char
Dim random As New Random
Dim answer As Integer
Dim low As Integer = 1
Dim high As Integer = 100
Dim Attempt As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MessageBox.Show("You pick a number between 0 and 100 and i will try to guess.Respond")
    answer = random.Next(1, 100)
    strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & answer, "Number Guessing Game")

    If strGuess = "L" Then
        low = answer
        LowFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "H" Then
        high = answer
        HighFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "R" Then
        MsgBox("I guessed it in " & Attempt & " tries")
    ElseIf strGuess = "X" Then
        End
    End If

End Sub

Private Function LowFunc(ByVal answer As Integer)

    Attempt = Attempt + 1

    answer = random.Next(low, high)
    strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & answer, "Number Guessing Game")

    If strGuess = "L" Then
        low = answer
        LowFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "H" Then
        high = answer
        HighFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "R" Then
        MsgBox("I guessed it in " & Attempt & " tries")
    ElseIf strGuess = "X" Then
        End
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Function HighFunc(ByVal answer As Integer)

    Attempt = Attempt + 1

    answer = random.Next(low, high)
    strGuess = InputBox("Is it " & answer, "Number Guessing Game")

    If strGuess = "H" Then
        high = answer
        HighFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "L" Then
        low = answer
        LowFunc(answer)
    ElseIf strGuess = "R" Then
        MsgBox("I guessed it in " & Attempt & " tries")
    ElseIf strGuess = "X" Then
        End
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
```

--

After reviewing this [Link](https://i.imgsafe.org/c4520011bc.jpg) provided by you, I updated this code. It will keep generating the random number between `high` and `low`. The values of `high` and `low` will be changed accordingly to input `H` or `L` which will be provided by player/user and when the right number will be guessed the player/user should give `R` as an input. They can give `X` as an input to quit the application. `Attempt` will show how many tried it took to guess the correct number.

Comment: Thanks for response.When i press `H` many time then it will giving me same number .Number will not change.After press 3,4 times `H` this will give same number.Number not change.Thanks

Comment: Mostly its works fine but some times it will stuck on same number

Comment: I updated the code after reviewing the Link provided by you.

Comment: Thanks alot man .You save me.Thank you again.You great sir.Please provide me your email sir.my email is `hameed7475@gmail.com`